# How do I make my c# Discord Bot notify my server when I upload a YouTube video to my channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

Hi so I got my discord bot setup and working in c# and I wanted to know how to make the bot notify my server whenever I upload a video to YouTube
If you want to see my code so far here it is:
[Open link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qPhcd37iTM3sXhIzKlGDVNigp7Y4H-mJ)

Comment: Could you perharps include the relevant code here instead of posting a google drive. Aka a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913009/how-to-call-a-function-when-a-youtube-user-uploads-a-video -> possible answer here

Comment: Question must be self-contain. here you simply state something and ask us to read a brunch of code on external source without knowing what we are looking for. And please be clear in your question those one line request are often too board, without code we don't know if you have issue getting the notification from YouTube or pushing it to Discord.

Comment: @DragandDrop I dont know what to be looking for in the code (I dont know where to start with the youtube side so I just posted everything)

Comment: You for sure have to use webhooks. Although if you care about the thing but have no problem using external app I'd suggest looking up ifttt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [WebHook](https://webhooks.pbworks.com/w/page/13385124/FrontPage), but there is no bot needed for this.  Essentially, a WebHook is a technique that causes an HTTP request to an API. In this instance, the HTTP request (usually a POST) will send the desired request to the Discord API and that API is responsible for handling the behavior. Luckily, Discord has this behavior implementation so the complexity of this task is rather low!

[This guide](http://mattdemers.com/guide-automate-discord-posts/) will show you how to do so with modern technologies.

Comment: I tried this before and it never worked, but if it does work now it will have to do, however I would prefer if the bot did it but this will do

Comment: The only way to do this that I can think of is to make the YouTube WebHook point to your bot, and the bot will send the API a message the bot formatted. This doesn't make sense though because Discord can handle WebHooks already. Although overly complicated, if you prefer this method I can get back to you on this.

Comment: the IFFIT webhook didnt work :(, so yes if you could tell me or find out how to make it work via the bot

Comment: Unfortunately, this might be too broad and complex to solve in a single post without extensive knowledge. However, I can point you in the right direction. Here is a tutorial with Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-generic-webhook-triggered-function

Comment: I found another webhook thing called Zapier, which works, thanks for the help

Comment: @TristanRead There is no way IFTTT didn't work. You probably did something wrong. Try YouTube and search for it. There are a lot of examples.